# How do I access a module's symbol table dynamically at runtime in Raku?

Tags: module, raku

I want to be able to pass my script the path to a `.rakumod` file, say `<blah>/Mod.rakumod`, and be able to access the symbol table as a hash as if I'd `use`d the module instead:

The module:

```
$ cat Mod.rakumod
unit module Mod;
sub bag        is export             { ... }
```

```
use lib <dir-containing-Mod>
use Mod;
say Mod::EXPORT::.keys
```

works, as [expected](https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Direct_lookup), returning `(ALL DEFAULT)`.

On the other hand:

```
use lib <dir-containing-Mod>
require Mod;
say Mod::EXPORT::.keys
```

fails with

```
Could not find symbol '&EXPORT' in 'Mod'
  in block <unit> at <blah>
```

This is despite the fact that even with `require`, `say Mod::.keys` does see `EXPORT`:

```
use lib <dir-containing-Mod>
require Mod;
say Mod::.keys
---
(EXPORT Mod)
```

I need to use `require` to make this [dynamic](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#require), as I don't know which module I'll want.

---

I *can* actually think of one thing to do, but it is absolutely disgusting:

- save my module name into a variable `$mod`
- have my script write *another* script `us`ing that module:

```
my $mod = <whatever>
my $cd = qq:to/END/;
use v6;
use lib qq\|\$\*CWD\|;
use $mod;

say {$mod}::EXPORT::ALL::.keys;
END

'aux.p6'.IO.spurt($cd);
```

- and then have the initial script call the auxiliary one:

```
shell("raku aux.p6")
```

What worked, per [raiph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67042596/11064961) (which I've accepted and am here paraphrasing):

- pass the path to the module and save it as `$path`;
- `use lib` the relevant directory:

```
my $dir = $path.IO.dirname;
use lib $dir;
```

- extract the plain file name:

```
my $modFile = S/(.*)\..*/$0/ with $path.IO.basename;
```

- finally, `require` that and pull the `.WHO` trick from [raiph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67042596/11064961), slightly adapted:

```
require ::($modFile);
say ::("{$modFile}::EXPORT::ALL").WHO.keys;
```

Run with `<script> <path>` that returned `(&bag)` all right.

---

Actually, the above doesn't quite work: `use lib $dir` will fail saying `$dir` is empty, because `use lib` isn't dynamic.

So instead I am now resorting to the unappealing solution of

- copying the module file to a temporary directory `./TMP`
- having called `use './TMP';`
- and then removing that directory when done.

Comment: If you won't know what module you'll want then you wouldn't do `require Mod`, rather `require ::("Mod");`

Comment: I know, but that's not the point: it's still a `require`, which won't give me access to the module as a hash. Here I was showing a simplified version, that doesn't use a string variable to hold the module path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use dynamic symbol lookup to get the symbol of the package whose symbols you want at run-time; then `.WHO` to get its stash; then `.keys` to get that stash's symbols.

For example:

```
use lib '.';
require Mod;
say ::Mod::EXPORT::('ALL').WHO.keys; # (&bag)
```

I'm going to make breakfast. I'll elaborate later.

Comment: Yes! That does it, even with the added complication noted by @ugexe. I will elaborate in another edit of the initial question, but also looking forward to your post-breakfast elaboration :)

Comment: @grobber I have most of my answer ready but am currently trying to properly discern what's going on with the difference between `foo::bar::` and `foo::bar.WHO` beyond the fact that `.WHO` works at run-time while the trailing `::` does not. The  specific code `package foo { our sub bar { package { } } }; say foo::bar::; # (<anon>)` is vexing me at the moment. What's that `<anon>`? I think my next step will be to go for a walk in the sun and eat a second breakfast. ;)

Comment: actually, the script in my 2nd edit does not quite work after all: it was only working because I was defaulting to `use lib "."` and had the module saved in the working directory. If I run from elsewhere it fails to find the module, because `use lib` is not dynamic..

Comment: I don't think your current problem is about  `use lib` not being dynamic (not sure what that means really); its almost certainly that you are passing a relative path instead of an absolute path

Comment: @ugexe: by "not dynamic" I meant that `my $path = "."; use lib $path` will fail complaining that `Repository specification can not be an empty string`. So: I can't resolve variables in `use lib`. And no, my paths were absolute: I was passing them on the command line as `~/<blah>/<moreblah>`, and the shell expands that to `/home/...`.

Comment: So you're having trouble with run time vs compile time. Long story short you can use `my $path = "."; CompUnit::RepositoryRegistry.use-repository(CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem.new(prefix => $path))`

Comment: Actually, even shorter! I discovered just now I can simply add my string to the [RAKULIB](https://docs.raku.org/programs/03-environment-variables#index-entry-RAKULIB) environment variable, bypassing `use lib` entirely. So something like `my $path=<whatever>; %*ENV{'RAKULIB'} = $path; require <module-in-that-directory>` works fine.

Comment: If you have total control of your system and are sure thats fine, yeah that will work. However in the general case I wouldn't suggest this since `RAKULIB` might have existing library paths required for e.g. dependencies.

Comment: @grobber  `my $path = "."; ` is a statement that does some of what it does at *compile-time* (declare the symbol `$path` and assign `Any` to it) and some at *run-time* (assign `"."` to it). `use lib $path;` is a statement that (afaik) does *all* of what it does at *compile-time* -- at which point `$path` is set to `Any`. Thus the error "Repository specification can not be an empty string." You'd need to write `BEGIN my $path = ".";` to have any chance of that working.

Comment: @grobber I'm still working on the update to my answer but have visited several rabbit holes along the way. If you currently don't have a solution, feel free to unaccept my answer, at least for now, and then you can accept it later when I get my update published if it solves your situation, or enough of it to get closure on this question so you can post a follow up, or invite other answers and accept any that gets you the solution you need. Or leave things as is. Your call of course.

Comment: @raiph thanks for the offer :), but as I feel the main piece of insight I was missing was the `.WHO` bit, I think I'll leave it as-is (i.e. accepted). Between that and the `RAKULIB` / `Compunit::Repository` suggestions in the exchange with @ugexe, I think I'm set.